# Sorting structured file with bash commands

Tags: awk, sort, ldap

I need to sort a LDIF file, where several lines belonging to a parent one.

Example

```
dn: 2

attr1: b

attr2: a

attr1: a

attr1: c



dn: 3

attr2: a

attr1: c

attr1: b

attr1: a



dn: 1

attr1: a

attr1: c

attr1: b

attr2: a
```

to this one

```
dn: 1

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a


dn: 2

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a


dn: 3

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a
```

So all parent line starting with dn are sorted, below all attrx are sorted and if attrx has multi values there are also sorted. I have done this with read line, but this takes hours on huge files. Is there a faster way to do same with bash commands?

An attribute value is always taking only one line. If there are multiples values each take one line.No line is base64 encoded.

Comment: In the real world, are your `dn` so simple as in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your example file

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file |awk -F'*' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s*", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' |sed 's/^*//' |awk -F'*' '{print $5"*"$1"*"$2"*"$3"*"$4}' |sort |awk -F'*' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n\n";ORS="\n\n\n"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}'
```

Convert every block of text to rows and using '*' to separate the fields

`awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
dn: 2*attr1: b*attr2: a*attr1: a*attr1: c
dn: 3*attr2: a*attr1: c*attr1: b*attr1: a
dn: 1*attr1: a*attr1: c*attr1: b*attr2: a`

Sort fields within the lines and using '*' to separate the fields

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file |awk -F'*' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s*", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' |sed 's/^*//'
```

`attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a *dn: 2
attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a *dn: 3
attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a *dn: 1`

rearrange the fieslds in the lines to 'print dn: x' in first place

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file |awk -F'*' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s*", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' |sed 's/^*//' |awk -F'*' '{print $5"*"$1"*"$2"*"$3"*"$4}'
```

`dn: 2*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a 
dn: 3*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a 
dn: 1*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a`

Sorting the lines by the first column or field

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file |awk -F'*' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s*", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' |sed 's/^*//' |awk -F'*' '{print $5"*"$1"*"$2"*"$3"*"$4}' |sort
```

`dn: 1*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a 
dn: 2*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a 
dn: 3*attr1: a *attr1: b *attr1: c *attr2: a`

Converting the rows to one column and inserting empty lines

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n\n";FS="\n\n";OFS="*";ORS=""} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file |awk -F'*' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s*", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' |sed 's/^*//' |awk -F'*' '{print $5"*"$1"*"$2"*"$3"*"$4}' |sort |awk -F'*' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n\n";ORS="\n\n\n"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}'

dn: 1

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a


dn: 2

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a


dn: 3

attr1: a

attr1: b

attr1: c

attr2: a
```

I know I'm using too much steps.